# d3 line chart labels overlap

Tags: d3.js, overlap, label, linechart

I've created a line chart based on the example found here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

However, with my data the line labels (cities) end up overlapping because the final values on the y-axis for different lines are frequently close together.  I know that I need to compare the last value for each line and move the label up or down when the values differ by 12 units or less.  My thought is to look at the text labels that are written by this bit of code

```
city.append("text")
.datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," +  y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
.attr("x", 3)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

If the y(d.value.temperature) values differ by 12 or less, move the values apart until they have at least 12 units between them.  Any thoughts on how to get this done?  This is my first d3 project and the syntax is still giving me fits!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off passing in all the labels at once -- this is also more in line with the general d3 idea. You could then have code something like this:

```
svg.selectAll("text.label").data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
       var currenty = y(d.value.temperature);
       if(i > 0) {
           var previousy = y(data[i-1].value.temperature),
           if(currenty - previousy < 12) { currenty = previousy + 12; }
       }
       return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," +  currenty + ")";
   })
   .attr("x", 3)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

This does not account for the fact that the previous label may have been moved. You could get the position of the previous label explicitly and move the current one depending on that. The code would be almost the same except that you would need to save a reference to the current element (`this`) such that it can be accessed later.

All of this will not prevent the labels from being potentially quite far apart from the lines they are labelling in the end. If you need to move every label, the last one will be pretty far away. A better course of action may be to create a legend separately where you can space labels and lines as necessary.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this only checks labels for adjacent lines for overlap.  If, for example, the label for line 1 and the label for line 3 overlap, that will not be detected and fixed with this routine.  Please let me know if I'm misinterpreting what this code does.  Thanks!

Comment: You are correct -- this would be taken into account by something that considered the location of the previous label instead of the previous data point though. My point is that it would almost certainly better to have a separate legend if you're having issues with label placement.

Comment: Point well taken...  Thanks for reassuring me that I'm not missing something easy.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a D3 force layout to place the labels. See an example here: https://bl.ocks.org/wdickerson/bd654e61f536dcef3736f41e0ad87786

Assuming you have a `data` array containing objects with a `value` property, and a scale `y`:

```
// Create some nodes
const labels = data.map(d => {
  return {
    fx: 0,
    targetY: y(d.value)
  };
});

// Set up the force simulation
const force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .nodes(labels)
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(10))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.targetY).strength(1))    
  .stop();

// Execute thte simulation
for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) force.tick();

// Assign values to the appropriate marker
labels.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y);
data.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
data.forEach((d, i) => d.y = labels[i].y);
```

Now your `data` array will have a `y` property representing its optimal position.

Example uses D3 4.0, read more here: https://github.com/d3/d3-force